# dask dataframe how to convert column to to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to convert one column of my dataframe to datetime. Following the discussion here https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/863 I tried the following code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df['time'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, columns='time').compute()
```

But I am getting the following error message

```
ValueError: Metadata inference failed, please provide `meta` keyword
```

What exactly should I put under meta? should I put a dictionary of ALL the columns in df or only of the 'time' column? and what type should I put? I have tried dtype and datetime64 but none of them work so far.

Thank you and I appreciate your guidance,

**Update**

I will include here the new error messages:

1) Using Timestamp

```
df['trd_exctn_dt'].map_partitions(pd.Timestamp).compute()

TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
```

2) Using datetime and meta

```
meta = ('time', pd.Timestamp)
df['time'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime,meta=meta).compute()
TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'meta'
```

3) Just using date time: gets stuck at 2%

```
    In [14]: df['trd_exctn_dt'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime).compute()
[                                        ] | 2% Completed |  2min 20.3s
```

Also, I would like to be able to specify the format in the date, as i would do in pandas:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = '%m%d%Y'
```

**Update 2**

After updating to Dask 0.11, I no longer have problems with the meta keyword. Still, I can't get it past 2% on a 2GB dataframe.

```
df['trd_exctn_dt'].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, meta=meta).compute()
    [                                        ] | 2% Completed |  30min 45.7s
```

**Update 3**

worked better this way:

```
def parse_dates(df):
  return pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')

df.map_partitions(parse_dates, meta=meta)
```

I'm not sure whether it's the right approach or not

Comment: what dask version are you on?

Comment: MRocklin, you were right, I updated to 0.11 version and now don't get any problems with the meta keyword. Still, it does 1 and 2% in less than 30 seconds, but it got stuck there for an hour. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I semi-solved it using defining a function to parse the dates and applying it using map partitions

Comment: From our experience using the `format` keyword always results in enhanced performance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Use `astype`

You can use the `astype` method to convert the dtype of a series to a NumPy dtype

```
df.time.astype('M8[us]')
```

There is probably a way to specify a Pandas style dtype as well (edits welcome)

#### Use map_partitions and meta

When using black-box methods like `map_partitions`, dask.dataframe needs to know the type and names of the output.  There are a few ways to do this listed in the docstring for `map_partitions`.

You can supply an empty Pandas object with the right dtype and name

```
meta = pd.Series([], name='time', dtype=pd.Timestamp)
```

Or you can provide a tuple of `(name, dtype)` for a Series or a dict for a DataFrame

```
meta = ('time', pd.Timestamp)
```

Then everything should be fine

```
df.time.map_partitions(pd.to_datetime, meta=meta)
```

If you were calling `map_partitions` on `df` instead then you would need to provide the dtypes for everything.  That isn't the case in your example though.

Comment: Thank you MRocklin! please see my updates in the question

Comment: does not work for me anymore with pandas 0.20, I get `dtype <class 'pandas._lib.tslib.Timestamp'> not understood`.
Works however with `meta = ('time', np.datetime64)`

Comment: It worked for me with no warning for future deprecation with `meta = ('time', 'datetime64[ns]')`

Comment: Here is a link to the [numpy datetime documentations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Answer (score 20):

Dask also come with to_timedelta so this should work as well.

```py
df['time']=dd.to_datetime(df.time,unit='ns')
```

The values unit takes is the same as pd.to_timedelta in pandas. This can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it this is the right approach, but mapping the column worked for me:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Works, but mapping lambdas is not good for performance.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

`ddf["Date"] = ddf["Date"].map_partitions(pd.to_datetime,format='%d/%m/%Y',meta = ('datetime64[ns]'))`

Comment: what if the Month is in this format: 'JAN' (note is uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

If the datetime is in a **non ISO format** then `map_partition` yields  better results:

```
import dask
import pandas as pd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()
ddf = ddf.assign(datetime=ddf.index.astype(object))
ddf = (ddf.assign(datetime_nonISO = ddf['datetime'].astype(str).str.split(' ')
                                 .apply(lambda x: x[1]+' '+x[0], meta=('object'))) 

%%timeit
ddf.datetime = ddf.datetime.astype('M8[s]')
ddf.compute()
```

11.3 s ± 719 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()
ddf = ddf.assign(datetime=ddf.index.astype(object))
ddf = (ddf.assign(datetime_nonISO = ddf['datetime'].astype(str).str.split(' ')
                                 .apply(lambda x: x[1]+' '+x[0], meta=('object'))) 


%%timeit
ddf.datetime_nonISO = (ddf.datetime_nonISO.map_partitions(pd.to_datetime
                       ,  format='%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d', meta=('datetime64[s]')))
ddf.compute()
```

8.78 s ± 599 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()
ddf = ddf.assign(datetime=ddf.index.astype(object))
ddf = (ddf.assign(datetime_nonISO = ddf['datetime'].astype(str).str.split(' ')
                                 .apply(lambda x: x[1]+' '+x[0], meta=('object'))) 

%%timeit
ddf.datetime_nonISO = ddf.datetime_nonISO.astype('M8[s]')
ddf.compute()
```

1min 8s ± 3.65 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)