# Read Large data from database table in pandas or dask

Tags: python, pandas, performance, bigdata, dask

I want to read all data from a table with 10+ gb of data into a dataframe. When i try to read with `read_sql` i get memory overload error. I want to do some processing on that data and update table with new data. How i can do this efficiently. My PC have 26gb of ram but data is max 11 gb of size, still i get memory overload error.

In Dask its taking so much time. Below is code.

```
import dateparser
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

df = dd.read_sql_table('fbo_xml_json_raw_data', index_col='id', uri='postgresql://postgres:passwordk@address:5432/database')
def make_year(data):
    if data and data.isdigit() and int(data) >= 0:
        data = '20' + data
    elif data and data.isdigit() and int(data) < 0:
        data = '19' + data
    return data

def response_date(data):
    if data and data.isdigit() and int(data[-2:]) >= 0:
        data = data[:-2] + '20' + data[-2:]
    elif data and data.isdigit() and int(data[-2:]) < 0:
        data = data[:-2] + '19' + data[-2:]
    if data and dateparser.parse(data):
        return dateparser.parse(data).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def parse_date(data):
    if data and dateparser.parse(data):
        return dateparser.parse(data).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df.ARCHDATE = df.ARCHDATE.apply(parse_date)
df.YEAR = df.YEAR.apply(make_year)
df.DATE = df.DATE + df.YEAR
df.DATE = df.DATE.apply(parse_date)
df.RESPDATE = df.RESPDATE.apply(response_date)
```

Comment: Does a simple operation like `len(df)`, before the processing, work? Note that you asking Dask to guess at partition sizes here, based on the bytes size of the first 5 rows - you may want to be more specific with the other kwargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

See that `chunksize` arg? You can chunk your data so it fits into memory.

It will return a chunk reading object so you can apply operations iteratively over the chunks.

You can probably also incorporate `multiprocessing` as well.

This will add a layer of complexity since you're no longer working on the DataFrame itself but an object containing chunks.

Since you're using `Dask` this "should" apply. I'm not sure how Dask handles chunking. It's been a while since I touched Pandas/Dask compatbility.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be the exclusive use of [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html). But `apply` is just a **row-wise Python-level loop**. It will be slow in Pandas *and* Dask. For performance-critical code, you should favour column-wise operations.

In fact, `dask.dataframe` supports a [useful subset](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html) of the Pandas API. Here are a couple of examples:-

#### Avoid string operations

Convert data to numeric types first; then perform vectorisable operations. For example:

```
dd['YEAR'] = dd['YEAR'].astype(int)
dd['YEAR'] = dd['YEAR'].mask(dd['YEAR'] >= 0, 20)
dd['YEAR'] = dd['YEAR'].mask(dd['YEAR'] < 0, 19)
```

#### Convert to datetime

If you have `datetime` strings in an appropriate format:

```
df['ARCHDATE'] = df['ARCHDATE'].astype('M8[us]')
```

See also [dask dataframe how to convert column to to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584118/dask-dataframe-how-to-convert-column-to-to-datetime).