# How can I speed up my code with dask in python?

Tags: dask

I tried to opend a csv.gzip file with Dask in Python. I will explain my code step by step.

First off I open the file with `dask.dataframe.read_csv`.At this step I specify the dtype and transform `'Date[G]','Time[G]'`to a single column.

```
dtype_dict= {'#RIC': 'str', 'Price': 'float', 'Volume': 'float'} 
df=dd.read_csv(f, compression='gzip',header=0, sep=',',
           quotechar='"',usecols=['#RIC','Date[G]','Time[G]','Price','Volume'],
                                  blocksize=None,parse_dates=[['Date[G]','Time[G]']],dtype=dtype_dict)
```

After that I drop all NA in `'Price','Volume'`columns and set the combined column `'Date[G]_Time[G]'`as index without drop the column since I still need it later.

```
df= df.dropna(subset=['Price','Volume'])
df=df.set_index('Date[G]_Time[G]', drop=False)
```

Then I tried to split that `'Date[G]_Time[G]'`column again since my output file needs date and time in two separate columns. I know there must be a better way to handle this, I just cannot find it.

```
df['Date[G]'] = dd.to_datetime(df['Date[G]_Time[G]']).dt.date
df['Time[G]'] = dd.to_datetime(df['Date[G]_Time[G]']).dt.time
df=df.drop(['Date[G]_Time[G]'],axis=1)
```

After that, I append that data frame to a list. I have a bunch of csv.gz files and I want to open all of them and then repartition this big data frame with a frequency of the calendar year.

```
dl=[]
df_concated=dl.append(df)
df_concated.repartition(freq='A')
```

I know under default dask can be really slow I just don't know how to set it which make me really upset. Does anyone know how to optimize my code?

Sample data.

```
 #RIC   Date[G]   Time[G]         Price Volume
 VZC.L 2014-05-01 06:16:00.480000 46.64 88.0
 VZC.L 2014-05-01 06:16:00.800000 46.64 33.0
 VZC.L 2014-05-01 06:16:00.890000 46.69 20.0
 VZC.L 2014-05-01 06:16:00.980000 46.69 40.0
 VZC.L 2014-05-01 06:16:01.330000 46.67 148.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the `read_csv` param `parse_dates`.

> parse_dates=[['Date[G]','Time[G]']]

Try to load the file without `parse_dates` as an `object` type and then convert the field to datetime.
see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584118/dask-dataframe-how-to-convert-column-to-to-datetime/56115170#56115170)